# Inserting Records into a database

Tags: sql, vb.net, insert, sqldatatypes

Whenever i run the code and try to run the SQL query it says Datatype mismatch
The code is as follows:

```
Public Class Form7
Public insert As New DBController
Public username, password, ID As String
Public chars(20) As Char
Public cc As Integer

Private Sub BTNSaveRecord_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTNSaveRecord.Click
    chars = TXTLastName.Text.ToCharArray
    ID = chars(0) & chars(1) & chars(2)
    insert.AddParameters("@ID", ID)
    insert.MakeQuery("SELECT Driver_ID FROM Driver WHERE Driver_ID LIKE '%@ID%'")
    ID = ID & (insert.recordcount + 120).ToString
    insert.clearDT()
    cc = Conversion.Val(TXTCarCapacity.Text)
    MsgBox(cc)
    insert.AddParameters("@ID", ID)
    insert.AddParameters("@Fname", TXTFirstName.Text)
    insert.AddParameters("@Lname", TXTLastName.Text)
    insert.AddParameters("@CarCap", cc)
    insert.AddParameters("@pass", "Password1")
    username = TXTFirstName.Text & TXTLastName.Text.First
    MsgBox(username)
    MsgBox(ID)
    insert.AddParameters("@user", username)
    insert.MakeQuery("INSERT INTO Driver (Driver_ID,Maximum_Case_Capacity,Driver_Username,Driver_Password,Driver_FirstName,Driver_LastName) " &
                     "VALUES (@ID,@CarCap,@user,@pass,@Fname,@Lname);")
End Sub
```

If you want to know the code for the DB controller i have the code. That is a self defined class to make the SQL stuff less repetitive. Like the data adapters command builders and datatables.

This is the table in the database I am inserting a new record in. This has no relationships too it that will stop me from entering a new record. The image contains the datatype types of each field
[image]
 Details for maximum_case_capacity
[image]

Comment: What are the details of `Maximum_Case_Capacity` on your database? Can you post a picture?

Comment: What happens when you debug this, get the query before it inserts, and run it manually on the DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access does not care what you call your parameters; the names are ignored. It is the order the parameters are added that matches them to the database. Since the order of the fields do not match the order the parameters are added you are getting a type mismatch when Access tries to add the string FName to the numeric field Maximum_Case_Capacity.

```
insert.AddParameters("@ID", ID)
insert.AddParameters("@CarCap", cc)
username = TXTFirstName.Text & TXTLastName.Text.First
insert.AddParameters("@user", username)
insert.AddParameters("@pass", "Password1")
insert.AddParameters("@Fname", TXTFirstName.Text)
insert.AddParameters("@Lname", TXTLastName.Text)
```

In a real application, you would never add passwords as plain text. Also, the interesting dance you do to get a unique primary key (maybe) could be avoided if you used a numeric autoincrement field in Access. I am afraid you will run out of space in that field rather quickly as it is only 6 characters wide. Hope you don't get too many people named Smith. ;-)

Comment: I don't know why but my teacher doesn't allow me to use the auto increment field for a primary key so didn't use it.

Comment: Teachers have their own ideas; just keep in the back of your mind that the options is available and a good idea in a multi user environment.

Comment: Will do. I'm still new to coding XD.